# how to delay automatically swiped view pager if user has done it manually

Tags: android, android-viewpager, timertask

I have view pager displaying three images from URL. In the on create main class I had set up a timer to swipe page after an interval.

> The problem is in both way the same method set current item is called how to distinguish whether it is called by a timer or manually by the user.

What I want to do.

**I want to delay the automation or reset the timer so that page swipe is not disturbed by a timer that is running behind. **

Need your valuable suggestion.here is the `[code(pastebin)][1]`

Comment: i have got my answer. If you can see this and know any good link to help me out share it. i am new to android developement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to override a method on your Activity

```
/*
    Called whenever a key, touch, or trackball event is dispatched to the activity. 
    Implement this method if you wish to know that the user has interacted
    with the device in some way while your activity is running.

    Note that this callback will be invoked for the touch down action
    that begins a touch gesture, but may not be invoked for the touch-moved 
    and touch-up actions that follow.

*/
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
   super.onUserInteraction();
   postPoneAnimation();  << do your postponing there
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate little more.

Comment: this method gets called every time the user touches the screen, that wait on every "user touch" you post pone the automated animation a few more seconds. After the user stop touching, it starts again. I'll add the docs for this method on the response.

Comment: old link but @Budis what if activity has two scrolling view. Like view pager and below that a  recyclerview .even On recyclerview's scroll          postPoneAnimation();  will be called